# JPA Buddy, JPA Entity from POJO transient attributes definition problem

Tags: jpa-buddy

I use the JPA Buddy (2023.3.5-232) plugin in the Intellij IDEA editor (Ultimate Edition 2023.2.3). My project is a SpringBoot application, and my database is a postgresql database.

JPA Entity from POJO functionality does not allow to define transient attribute

The problem occurs in case of an XMLGregorianCalendar dto's field type giving the error warning "Entity attribute should have a name written in camelCase naming convention"
Please note thet field name is corrrectly in camel case convention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, JPA Buddy doesn't allow to define that yet. It looks as sensible improvement, I created a ticket for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JPAB-2681/Add-ability-to-make-an-attribute-transient-for-Entity-from-POJO